# Do I need to use dataType : 'json' in my AJAX function and PHP code in order to make the value from PHP file accessible in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I've a following AJAX function code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#btn_add_event").click(function(){

        var strSeriaze = $( "#formAddEvent" ).serialize();
        url = $( "#formAddEvent" ).attr('action');
        $("#btn_add_event").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("#addEventErrorMsg").html('');
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: "POST",
          data:  {postData:strSeriaze},
          beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader-icon').show();
          },
          complete: function() {
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
          }, //Code from success function is not working
          success: function(data) {
          $('#loader-icon').hide();
          if(data) {
            $("#myModal-add-event").modal('hide');
            $("#myModal-add-event").hide();
            window.location.href = site_url + "event_index.php?event_id="+data;
            return false;
          } else {
            $("#btn_add_event").attr('disabled', false);
            $("#addEventErrorMsg").show();
            $("#addEventErrorMsg").html(data);
          }
        },
        error: function() { }
      });         
    })
  });
```

The function is working fine giving calls to the PHP file contained in variable `url`. No issues in calling the PHP file.

The necessary PHP file code is below :

```
<?php
  $ret = $objEvent->addEvent($eventData);

  if($ret){
    $eventAddResultArr = $objEvent->GetResponse();

    if($eventAddResultArr['msg'] == 'Success') {
      //$_SESSION['msg'] = "Event added successfully." . 
      echo $eventAddResultArr['data']; //$eventAddResultArr['data'] contains integer value 332
    //Code gets stuck here only and prints the value 332 on a pop-up, the pop-up doesn't get close since the code written for it is getting working. The code is written in success function.  
    exit;
    }
?>
```

Now what is happening is upon successful call to the PHP file the execution stops after statement `echo $eventAddResultArr['data'];`.

Actually I want to access this value in my success function but I'm not able to do it.

I think this is happening due to incompatible data types or something else. Also in firebug console there is no error in response it shows 332 only. That means the control is not getting returned from PHP file or there might be some issue in returning the control back to AJAX function.

Can somebody please help me by correcting the mistake I'm making and by correcting my code to make the things working.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get `console.log(data)` in `success`?

Comment: Problem with `if(data)` it always goes to `else` data is integer value. You have to check `if(data!=null && data.msg=="Success")`